# Main class not found with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, rgb, program-entry-point

This same thing happened to me before and i couldn't fix it. It can not find a main

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;

public class Final {
   static PointerInfo pointer;
   static Point point;
   static Robot robot;
   static Color color;
   private static PopupMenu Pan;

   public static void main() {
      JFrame F = new JFrame("RGB");
      F.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      F.getContentPane().add(Pan);
      F.pack();
      F.setSize(300, 300);
      F.setVisible(true);
      F.setSize(300, 300);
      try {
         robot = new Robot();
         while (true) {
            pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            point = pointer.getLocation();
            if (point.getX() == 0 && point.getY() == 0) {
               break;
            } else {
               color = robot.getPixelColor((int) point.getX(),
                     (int) point.getY());
               System.out.println("Color at: " + point.getX() + ","
                     + point.getY() + " is: " + color);
            }
         }
      } catch (AWTException | HeadlessException e) {
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your main method signature is wrong. You need the String[] args parameter.

In other words, this:

```
public static void main() {
```

should be this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

---

As an aside: your mixture of Swing code with a `while (true)` block is a dangerous thing to do. It may work in this toy program where everything is created in the main method, but once you move to something just a little more advanced, it will always lock up your GUI.

---

Next: you should almost **never** have an empty catch block. This is the programming equivalent of driving a motorcycle with your eyes closed. At least print a stacktrace.

---

Next, you'll want to get most of that code out of the main method and into proper classes with non-static methods and fields.